# Find the equivalent capacity of this circuit

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

I wonder how to obtain the equivalent capacity of the circuit below.I think adding a voltage source and using KVL would be a nice idea but I don't know how to apply it.any hints would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Hint : Delta-Wye conversion.

Comment: Delta-Wye conversion is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform). If you get stuck post what you have tried. You are not going to get a detailed answer here without showing some effort first.

Comment: I have answered a similar question recently [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217313/capacitance-node-calculation/217528#217528). In fact, it reduces down to a very similar circuit in my answer, this question could almost be considered a duplicate.

Comment: The first thing I saw was the out of focus picture.  That made me not want to read the rest, just downvote and close this mess.  So I did.  Go away until you've learned to show some respect to those you seek a favor from.

Comment: sorry I couldn't check for a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are only talking about lumped-parameters here, i.e. DC analysis, this can be solved by Star-Delta conversion (also called Delta-Y conversion).

Visualize this circuit as two deltas-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flJCak.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first delta consists of C1,C2 and C3. And the second delta consists of C4,C5 and C3.

It also consists of two Ys or Stars. The first Y consists of C1,C4 and C3. And the second Y consists of C2,C5 and C3.

First step:

One can choose to convert one of the Deltas into a Y/Star. Or you can convert one of the Y/Star into a Delta.

Let's convert the First Y/Star into a Delta and deal with the circuit. Convert the Y consisting of C1,C4 and C3. We get another circuit with Z1,Z2 and Z3 with values C1*C4/(C1+C3+C4), C1*C3/(C1+C3+C4) and C3*C4/(C1+C3+C4)

New capacitance values are Z1 = 6/6 = 1uF, Z2 = 2/6 = 1/3uF and Z3 = 3/6 = 0.5uF

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxlFo5.png)</sup>

Now this is easy. Rewire the schematic and you'll see it it just a series and parallel capacitors problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2furI2N.png)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You have:
$$C{_e} = (2F // C{_{e1}}) -- 2F$$
And: $$C{_{e1}} = 3F -- (1F // 2F)$$

Now you have to do it your self to find the Ce.
Note: __ means series and // parallel

Comment: Is that supposed to be helpful?

Comment: This is incorrect. The 1F and 2F you have used in Ce1 are not in parallel. Delta-Wye conversion is the correct way to answer this.